# Add thermal effect to Image

Tags: images, android

I am an Android Developer(not graphic Designer). So i have to do all the step in Coding.

I want to add thermal effect to Image. What are the steps of it.

I have added night vision effect to it by setting red and blue to zero. then only green is on .it look like night vision. So what color saturation ,hue, or rgb value. I should set to get this effect.

and i have asked a question at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645950/how-can-i-add-thermal-effect-to-yuv-image)

Comment: i don't know how to do this with programming, but its maybe helpful http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/How-to-Create-a-Predator-Thermal-Vision-Effect-with-Photoshop/81672

Comment: http://www191.lunapic.com/editor/?action=thermal

Comment: Hi Zar-e-ahmer, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Coud you please include soem screenshots? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Please don't cross post across sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of an odd question, since you are coming specifically from the programming side of things, but I'm a front-end developer myself so I can appreciate this.

The difficult part with Thermal-style imaging is that some areas are bright and intense (where the heat is) and the other areas are very dark and muted (where there is no heat). Because of this, there are actually two layers of effects that have to be performed.

1. The first layer is to remove all the red and green. Red and green are used to indicate heat, so by removing all of it, we are removing all the base heat. You will be left with a dark blue hued image to use as a background.
2. The second layer is to choose which objects are "hot" and colour them as such. By only selecting those objects, and then applying a gradient map (where each colour is mapped to a different colour on the gradient spectrum) and using a rainbow gradient for the gradient reference, you should get a nice wacky looking "hot" image. You take that new image and red shift it, removing (but not completely removing) the blue and some of the green.

Here is a step-by-step Photoshop tutorial from which I take reference:
http://www.dreevoo.com/content.php?id=1639

Although not programmatically done, this method is the closest way that I, from a GD persepective, can help out.